# Will I get the season 1 and 2 characters with the free Arcade Edition update?

Tags: street-fighter-v

Will I get the season 1 and 2 characters for free with the free Arcade Edition update?

I just want to know whether I can get the content for free if I wait for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will get the season one and two characters if you buy the Arcade Edition or wait for the free update.

[Source](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gaming/news/street-fighter-v-arcade-edition-coming-next-year-free-update/):

> If you've not picked Street Fighter V up yet, and purchase Street Fighter V: Arcade Edition, you'll also get access to both the Season 1 DLC characters and the Season 2 DLC characters, on top of all the free updates. So, the full list of changes is as follows:
>
> - Arcade Mode
> - Extra Battle Mode
> - New V-trigger moves
> - Gallery
> - New User Interface
>
> That all comes either with Street Fighter V: Arcade Edition, or as a free update on January 16, 2018.